# Simple number validation using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expression. I need to validate the following using regular expression:

- an input string is digit only between 6 and 10 characters long

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Comment: Combining your regex with a java number class such as BigDecimal will assist you to remove leading and trailing unnecessary zero's of the number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following RegEx, `\\d{6,10}`. This would match any string which has only digits and the number of times digits can occur is 6 to 10.

*(By digit we mean any character with the Unicode General Category of Nd (Number, Decimal Digit.) as Java uses the ICU Regular Expressions libraries.)*

You can see how the RegEx works [here](http://regex101.com/r/mL4wM9)

```
    String pattern = "\\d{6,10}", myString = "111111";
    System.out.println(myString.matches(pattern));
```

would print

```
true
```

Comment: Thank you not only for the answer, but also for the regex tester site. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: You really don't need the anchors, since you are using `String#matches()`; it acts as if the anchors are already there (if you don't believe me, try it out).

Comment: It's not correct that this regex matches "any string which starts and ends with a number". This matches

Comment: @Behe As long as the length is within the range 6-10 and it has only numbers, it matches OP's requirement :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: My comment is about the formulation, not the regex itself: "Only numbers" is different than "any string which starts and ends with a number".

Comment: @Behe I think I havnt understood that comment properly. Could you please show me few strings for which the RegEx will fail?

Comment: @thefourtheye: Your regex is totally fine, as it matches "only digits". It is only about the description of the regex: the formulation you used "This would match any string which starts and ends with a number" is incorrect. The latter description also includes strings that have _non-digits_ in the middle. I think it would be better to change this description to something with "only digits".

Comment: @Behe Aah... Got it :) Thanks for taking your time to correct me :)

Comment: @thefourtheye can u pls tell how to validate number without range.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code

```
[0-9]{6, 10}
```

or

```
\d{6, 10}
```

enjoy !